# How to assert that condition is fulfilled eventually?

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I'm trying to write a JUnit5 tests that asserts that a conditions is fullfilled eventually in the next 15 seconds. How can I best implement that?

I was thinking something about this:

```
    assertTimeout(ofSeconds(15), () -> {assertThat(condition, is(true));});
```

But it should repeatedly test the condition

Comment: Out of scope: You know, that such a test is a recipe for eventually failing CI. Better is to test the event without any timerfunction. But I don't know your usecase, I just recommend to keep that in mind.

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at [Awaitility](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility), it has the functionality that you are looking for. ([docs here](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility/wiki/Usage))

```
@Test
public void updatesCustomerStatus() throws Exception {

  // Publish an asynchronous event:
  publishEvent(updateCustomerStatusEvent);
  // Awaitility lets you wait until the asynchronous operation completes:
  await().atMost(5, SECONDS).until(customerStatusIsUpdated());
  ...
}
```